# How can I ensure that a Gulp pipeline has completed before the next task in an Azure devops pipeline?

Tags: javascript, azure-devops, gulp, azure-pipelines, bundling-and-minification

I'm using Gulp in an Azure devops pipeline. The task is to bundle some CSS files using `gulp-concat`, then publish the artifact.

One task runs Gulp using this...

```
const gulp = require("gulp"),
      concat = require("gulp-concat"),
      fs = require("gulp-fs");

function doBundle(callback) {
    var result = gulp.src([
            ...
        ])
        .pipe(concat("bundle.css"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./Content/"));

    console.info(fs.existsSync("./Content/bundle.css"));
    
    return result;
}

gulp.task("default", gulp.series(doBundle));
```

The subsequent task in the pipeline publishes the artifact found at `./Content/bundle.css`, but this fails, saying that no such file exists.

True enough, looking at the console I can see that the line...

```
console.info(fs.existsSync("./Content/bundle.css"));
```

...is returning `false`. However, if I introduce a delay by changing that line to...

```
setTimeout(() => {
        console.info(fs.existsSync("./Content/bundle.css"));
    },
    2000);
```

... then it returns `true`.

My assumption is therefore that the devops pipeline is moving to the next task before the Gulp task has completed. If this is correct, what's the best practice here?

How can I ensure that the Gulp pipeline has completed before the next task in the Azure devops pipeline?

Comment: Maybe remove the unused `callback` argument from the task function.